# collectd plugins installation?

Tags: collectd

I'm starting to configure collectd, but the main problem I got is that when I load the Network plugin it says next:

> Could not find plugin network.
>   Found a configuration for the `network' plugin, but the plugin isn't loaded or didn't register a configuration callback.

No idea why, should I install every single plugin? I thought it was installed by default, and... how should I install a plugin?

Comment: Just in case, I set up the plugins path as: PluginDir "../lib/collectd"

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute plugins path, i.e. "/usr/lib/collectd"? Is the "network.so" file there?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Each time I want to start collectd I have the error messages Could not find plugin dns. Coud not find plugin nut Did you manage to solve your problem ? The strange thing being that, in my case, everything was working fine until a power outage obliged me to reboot the machine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to note is that there is a HUGE difference between collectd 4 and collectd 5  .. Most distributions ship with collectd4, but the project site suggests it is outdated, and my encounters with version4 reveals much inconsistencies.

I will suggest that you do all you can to ensure you install collectd5 (instead of version 4.x) ..

As to plugins, you will find that the default install comes with all the plugins to satisfy most needs.

The config files imply that just copying the compiled '.so' files and adding the appropriate Loadplugin statements should be OK, but in my experience, plugins I tried would not work with this process.  So, if you cannot find OS-packaged plugins, your best option would be to build from sources